# How to assign multiple lines to a string variable in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, multiline, multilinestring

I have a few lines of text like this:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

and I want to assign these multiple lines to a Matlab variable for further processing.

I am copying these from very large text file and want to process it in Matlab Instead of saving the text into a file and then reading line by line for processing.

I tried to handle the above text lines as single string but am getting an error whilst trying to assign to a variable:

```
x = 'abc
def
ghi'
```

Error:

```
x = 'abc
        |
Error: String is not terminated properly.
```

Any suggestions which could help me understand and solve the issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I frequently do this, namely copy text from elsewhere which I want to hard-code into a MATLAB script (in my case it's generally SQL code I want to manipulate and call from MATLAB).

To achieve this I have a helper function in `clipboard2cellstr.m` defined as follows:

```
function clipboard2cellstr

str = clipboard('paste');
str = regexprep(str, '''', ''''''); % Double any single quotes
strs = regexp(str, '\s*\r?\n\r?', 'split');
cs = sprintf('{\n''%s''\n}', strjoin(strs, sprintf('''\n''')));
clipboard('copy', cs);
disp(cs)
disp('(Copied to Clipboard)')

end
```

I then copy the text using Ctrl-c (or however) and run `clipboard2cellstr`. This changes the contents of the clipboard to something I can paste into the MATLAB editor using Ctrl-v (or however).

For example, copying this line

and this line

and this one, and then running the function generates this:

```
{
'For example, copying this line'
'and this line'
'and this one, and then running the function generates this:'
}
```

which is valid MATLAB which can be pasted directly in.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for exact this functionality. Thanks once again

Answer (score 2):

Your error is because you ended the line when MATLAB was expecting a closing quote character. You must use array notation to have multi-line or multi-element arrays.

---

You can assign like this if you use array notation

```
x = ['abc'
     'def'
     'hij']
>> x = 3×3 char array
```

Note: with this method, your rows must have the same number of characters, as you are really dealing with a [character array](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html). You can think of a character array like a numeric matrix, hence why it must be "rectangular".

If you have MATLAB R2016b or newer, you can use the [`string`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/string.html) data type. This uses double quotes `"..."` rather than single quotes `'...'`, and can be multi-line. You must still use array notation:

```
x = ["abc"
     "def"
     "hijk"]
>> x = 3×1 string array
```

We can have different numbers of characters in each line, as this is simply a 3 element string array, not a character array.

Alternatively, use a cell array of character arrays (or strings)

```
x = {'abc'
     'def'
     'hijk'}
>> x = 3×1 cell array
```

Again, you can have character arrays or strings of different lengths within a cell array.

---

In all of the above examples, a newline is simply for readability and can be replaced by a semi-colon `;` to denote the next line of the array.

---

The option you choose will depend on what you want to do with the text. If you're reading from a file, I would suggest the string array or the cell array, as they can deal with different length lines. For backwards compatibility, use a cell array. You may find `cellfun` relevant for operating on cell arrays. For native string operations, use a string array.

Comment: I have approx 10 text lines and copying them from file and want to avoid to add '' or "" in each line. I want to find a way to bypass this step.

Comment: I want to repeat this process again and again. Copy some part of huge file and process it and repeat it...

Comment: You can try `textscan`

Comment: Sounds like you're copy and pasting lines of your file into your Matlab code? Simply read in the file (using `textscan` as Adiel suggests or perhaps `fscanf`) and append to one of the above array types as needed. You shouldn't have to manually add `' '` or `" "` when reading from a file, these just denote which variable type you're dealing with in the examples / when using manual input.